# How to solve $(z+i)(\overline{z}-i)^2(zi-1)^3=64$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I tried to solve $(z+i)(\overline{z}-i)^2(zi-1)^3=64$. I noticed that$$(z+i)(\overline{z}-i)^2(zi-1)^3 = -i(z+i)^4(\overline{z}-i)^2$$and $\left(\frac{(z+i)^2(\overline{z}-i)}{8}\right)^2=i$. How to finish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}(z+i)\left(\overline z-i\right)^2(zi-1)^3&=(z+i)\left(\overline z-i\right)^2(zi+i^2)^3\\&=i^3(z+i)\left(\overline z-i\right)^2(z+i)^3\\&=-i(z+i)^2\left(\overline z-i\right)^2(z+i)^2\\&=-i|z+i|^4(z+i)^2\end{align}and that therefore\begin{align}2^6&=64\\&=\left|-i|z+i|^4(z+i)^2\right|\\&=|z+i|^6.\end{align}So, $|z+i|=2$. It follows that$$64=-i|z+i|^4(z+i)^2\iff 64=-16i(z+i)^2.$$So, your equation is equivalent to$$(z+i)^2=4i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+yi$, where $\{x,y\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, we have
$$i^3(z+i)^4(x-yi-i)^2=64$$ or
$$(x+(y+1)i)^4(x-(y+1)i)^2=64i$$ or
$$(x^2+(y+1)^2)^2(x+(y+1)i)^2=64i$$ or
$$(x^2+(y+1)^2)^2(x^2-(y+1)^2+2x(y+1)i)=64i,$$
which gives $$(x^2+(y+1)^2)^2(x^2-(y+1)^2)=0$$ and since $x^2+(y+1)^2=0$ is impossible, we obtain
$$x^2=(y+1)^2$$ and
$$2x(y+1)(x^2+(y+1)^2)^2=64.$$
We see that $y+1=x$ only, which gives $x^2=2$.

Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it quite like that.

Consider $-i(z+i)^4(\bar z-i)^2=64$. We have $(z+i)(\bar z-i)$ is a product of complex conjugates and is therefore real. So we must have $(z+i)^2$ is purely imaginary.

Now $(x+iy+i)^2=x^2-y^2-1+2xyi+2xi-2y$ and the real part of this is $x^2-(y+1)^2=0$ so that $x=y+1$ or $x=-y-1$

This means that $z+i=x (1\pm i)$ and the complex conjugate is $\bar z-i = x(1\mp i)$

Now you should be able to create a simpler equation you can solve.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tricks: $zi-1=i(z+i)$ and $\overline z-i=\overline{z+i}$, so that the whole expression is

$$i^3(z+i)^4\overline{(z+i)^2}=i^3(z+i)^2|z+i|^4=64.$$

In polar form, $z+i=r\text{ cis }\theta$,

$$r^6\text{cis}(2\theta-\pi)=64$$

and

$$r=2,\theta=\frac\pi2+k\pi,$$

$$z=\pm\sqrt2(1+i)-i.$$